# Cypress submitting form with preventDefault

Tags: integration-testing, cypress, svelte, sapper

I am having trouble using Cypress.

There are 2 problems I'm currently having.

1. A form with preventDefault is being submitted and the page is refreshing.
2. I have to `.click()` and input before I can `.type()` into it.

--

I have a form that has preventDefault, and you can see from the test that it submites the form, which adds a empty query string to the url, and none of my error handling messages are shown. This doesn't actually happen when I use the app myself.

```
    it('requires email', () => {
        cy.visit('/sign-in')
        cy.get('form').contains('Sign in').click()
        cy.get('.errors').should('contain', 'Email is required.')
    })
```

I am using Svelte/Sapper as my front-end.

[image]

Form:

```
<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <Input label="Email" type="email" bind:value={email} />
    <Input label="Password" type="password" bind:value={password} />
    <Button text="Sign in" />
</form>
```

---

The second issue is that I have to `.click()` and input in my test before I can `.type()` into it.

I have to do this:

`cy.get('#email').click().type('user@example.com{enter}')`

Instead of this:

`cy.get('#email').type('user@example.com{enter}')`

I am not sure why this is happening. If I don't click the field, it says the field may have the attribute `disabled`, which it doesn't. When I test it myself, I don't see any issues, and the dom snapshots in Cypress don't reveal anything unusual.

Perhaps it has to do with autofill?

Has anyone run into these problems?

Comment: First off, please share the test code that you use for finishing the form. Currently I have no clue why that is happening, although I'd try a raw submit-handler preventing the default action, to ensure it's not something with that weird `|preventDefault`. Secondly I'm suprised `get("#email")` even selects anything, you don't have an ID email, and you should use `data-cy` attributes anyway per best practices: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html

Comment: I have added my test code above.
- I have tried a raw submit handler, passing in the event to my function and calling `e.preventDefault`, same issue
- The `Input` is a svelte component, and I can assure that email has an ID of #email and password as #password. Cypress properly selects these elements
- The weird `|preventDefault` are Svelte's event modifiers, and are pretty standard: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-modifiers

Comment: Thank you for your `data-cy` suggestion, I am using that now, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with Sapper is that it is SSR, so the app was not hydrated before Cypress started running tests, which was causing a whole bunch of issues.

The solution was to tell Cypress to wait until the app was hydrated. This was accomplished by setting an attribute in the return to the promise from `sapper.start` and then overwriting the Cypress visit command.

client.js:

```
sapper.start({
    target: document.querySelector("#app"),
}).then(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute('hydrated', '')
})
```

Cypress commands:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (orig, url, options) => {
    orig(url, options)
    cy.get('body[hydrated]').should('have.length', 1)
})
```

Now everything works and tests are passing.