# How to stub node server function using Cypress

Tags: cypress, sapper

I am using Sapper, which has a `preload` function before it loads the page. This preload function is on a node server, allowing the page to hydrate. Cypress doesn't seem to stub the API requests in this preload function.

Thoughts on how to stub these requests?

Cypress stub:

```
cy.server()
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'v1/preference',
  status: 200,
  response: {}
}).as('postPreference')
```

My preload function:

```
<script context='module'>
    import * as api from 'api.js'

    export async function preload(params, session) {
        const { user } = session
        if (!user) { return this.redirect(302, 'sign-in') }
        const preference = await api.get('v1/preference', session.token)
        return { preference }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Sapper is SSR, the preload function gets called on the node server when the page is requested for the first time. When navigating to different pages, this preload function is then called in the browser, allowing you to stub those API requests.

My solution was to create an access route used strictly for testing that hydrates the app, and redirects to the requested page, allowing the page's preload function to be called.

testing/routes.svelte

```
<script context='module'>
    // See /cypress/support/commands.js #visitLocal
    export async function preload(page, session) {
        const { query } = page
        const href = query.href
        if (!href) { return this.redirect(302, '/') }
        return { href }
    }
</script>

<script>
    import { goto } from '@sapper/app'
    export let href
    goto(href)
</script>
```

Cypress commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('visitLocal', (path) => {
  cy.visit(`testing/routes?href=${path}`, { failOnStatusCode: false })
  cy.hydrated() // https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374676/13124916
})
```

Use in test:
`cy.visitLocal('route-you-want-to-test-with-preload-being-called')`